# MRTK - how to implement a Touch Slider in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

As seen on a video of the HoloLens 2 presentation it is possible to have a pinch slider, a touch slider and also a push slider. Poorly there is only a prefab for a pinch slider and I can't get the slider to work also as a touch slider.

Which version of the MRTK was supporting the touch slider? Couldn't find any version >= 2.5.0.

How can I do this? I thought adding a `NearInteractionTouchable` script on the thumbRoot button would help but it does not.
[image]

Comment: I tested on MRTK 2.5.3 and it works for me without any additional script. Did you set the MixedRealityToolkit configuration correctly?

Comment: I don't mean the pinch slider you can see here. https://youtu.be/uIHPPtPBgHk?t=168 look at the timestamp in the video. I mean this kind of sliders.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the value by poking with one finger in MRTK 2.7.2, please check out the TouchSliderExample.unity which is located at /MRTK/Examples/Experimental/TouchSlider/Scenes.